# what should I choose if I charge my app per device in appstore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

My app is for iPad only. I need post my app to app store these days for selling.The app is charged per device and each device is considered as a user. In appstore,there're 2 types of product that I can register:
1, Non-Consumable: purchased once but for all devices of the user.
2, Non-Renewable subscription: purchase based on the duration but for all devices of the user.

None of product types match my current app charge mode (each device installed my app must be charged ). How can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that. Users must be able to install on any device that Apple allows them to install on. There may be a limit to the total number of simultaneous installs (5?) but the idea is that one Apple ID owns one copy of your program and can run it on any of their devices.

Comment: I just wanna let the user purchase license like microsoft office suite.You purchase 50 license means you can only install office suite on 50 computers. Server-side control is the only way?

Comment: You should talk to Apple and see what they say. In general, they don't like things that don't fit in one of their existing boxes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by In-App Purchases. 
So the App is basically free to download but to use the features you need to do an In-App-Purchase. You shouldn't use Consumable here, because if one buys a license and deinstalls the app (or get's a new device) he would have to buy it again although he is just using one device. 
So I would set the In-App Purchase to non-consumable, but tracking the purchases.

To track the purchase you need a server and you need to generate some kind of UDID (unique id for the device) and link it to a user account.
When the user now clicks on (I already bought or buy in-app purchase) you first ask the Apple Store like you always do for an in-app Purchase, but after this was successful ask your server if he needs to buy another license or if he wants to move the license to this device or another appropriate action for your licensing model.